# When is the quotient of entire functions entire

Tags: complex-analysis

I am aware that a sufficient condition is that the denominator is nowhere zero.

But assuming two functions with a nonempty set of zeros, I would like to know alternative conditions for the quotient to be entire.

None of the complex analysis textbooks I've looked give any results.

Comment: Another case would be where all zeros of the denominator are also zeros of the numerator, with multiplicities not greater than the ones in the numerator.

Comment: Michael's excellent comment is not just "another case": it is the necessary and sufficient condition for the quotient to be entire. The result is an immediate consequence of the local structure of a holomorphic $f$ at a point $a\in \mathbb C$, namely $f(z)=(z-a)^n u(z)$ with $u$ holomorphic and non-zero at $a$.